# Template function instantiated with different types

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm attempting to build a basic but generic gradient generating function.  The goal is to have a function `gradient` which takes a function and variadic parameters, and returns a vector of the complex values at the points provided.  The code is as follows:

`grad.h`

```
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
/**base case*/
template<typename FNC, typename T>
auto gradientHelper(FNC&& fnc, std::vector<T>&& val){
    return std::move(val);
}

/**recursive case*/
template<typename FNC, typename T,  typename...Ts>
auto gradientHelper(const FNC& fnc, std::vector<T>&& val, const T& current, const Ts&... others){
    val.emplace_back(fnc(std::complex<T>(current, 1.0), others...).imag());
    return gradientHelper(
        [&](const Ts&... others){
        return fnc(current, others...);
    }, std::move(val), others...);
}

/**calling case*/
template<typename FNC, typename T, typename...Ts>
auto gradient(FNC&& fnc, const T& param, const Ts&... params){
    return gradientHelper(fnc, std::vector<T>(), param, params...);
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "grad.h"
#include <vector>
int main(){
    auto myTestFunc=[](const auto& x, const auto& y){
        return x*y;//gradient should be [y, x]
    };
    double testX=2;
    double testY=3;
    std::vector<double> answer({testY, testX});
    gradient(myTestFunc,  testX, testY);
}
```

Compile with `g++ -std=c++14 -O3 main.cpp`

I get the following error: `no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::complex<double>’ to ‘const double&’`

I understand why I get this error.  I've instantiated the function passed into `gradient` with parameter types `complex, double` and then called it again with parameter types `double, complex`.  My question is how to get around this limitation.  I don't have much experience with variadic or SFINAE coding and the resources I've used to help have not pointed me in the right direction.  Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Made the code have no dependencies except for standard library.

Edit2: Made Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand what you mean with "'AutoDiff' library which when passed as a value to a function returns the function and the derivative" and " I've instantiated the first function with parameter types AutoDiff, double and then called it again with parameter types double, AutoDiff". Can you explain?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I made it  a "std::complex" instead of "AutoDiff".  "AutoDiff" is essentially the same as "std::complex" except with different overloaded math operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing the code as follows:

```
template<typename FNC, typename T,  typename...Ts>
auto gradientHelper(const FNC& fnc, std::vector<T>&& val, const T& current, const Ts&... others){
    val.emplace_back(fnc(std::complex<T>(current, 1.0), others...).imag());
    return gradientHelper(
        /*This won't work! The template is already defined!*/
        /*[&](const Ts&... others){
        return fnc(current, others...);*/

        /*This will work!  The remaining parameters 
          are deduced on the next call*/
        [&](const auto&... remaining){
           return fnc(current, remaining...);
        }
    }, std::move(val), others...);
}
```